# connectedComponentsWithStats return types and values in Java

Tags: java, opencv

I am trying to get the centroid of one or more blobs from a binary image (preferably only if the blob's area exceeds a threshold).

A `findContours` solutions works, but not perfectly and the `FeatureDetetector.SIMPLEBLOB` alternative works just like I want it, but is really slow.

Now I am trying `connectedComponentsWithStats` but have no clue how to interpret and use the result, because it uses Mats where I wouldn't expect them and the documentation is not a big help.

How do I access the relevant information such as centriod x, y and area?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Centroids as well as bounding boxes of the connected regions are saved in each line of the resulting Mats. In the labeled image you can find the regions as consecutive indexes. To extract the centroids, bounding boxes and regions images you can use this class. It's intended to extract dark regions in a near white background. Background region is skipped.

Notice that you must call 'release' method when you finish using a Segmentation object.

```
import org.opencv.core.*;
import org.opencv.imgproc.Imgproc;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

public class Segmentation {

    private Region[] regions = null;
    private Mat labeled = null;

    public Segmentation(Mat image, int bwThreshold) {

        Mat gray = new Mat(image.size(), CvType.CV_8U);

        if (image.type() != CvType.CV_8U) {
            Imgproc.cvtColor(image, gray, Imgproc.COLOR_BGR2GRAY);
        } else {
            image.copyTo(gray);
        }

        Mat bw = Mat.zeros(image.size(), image.type());
        Imgproc.threshold(gray, bw, bwThreshold, 255, Imgproc.THRESH_BINARY_INV);

        createRegions(bw);

        // Free memory
        kernel.release();
        gray.release();
        bw.release();
    }

    public Segmentation(Mat image) {
        this(image, 210);
    }

    private void createRegions(Mat image) {
        labeled = new Mat(image.size(), image.type());

        // Extract components
        Mat rectComponents = Mat.zeros(new Size(0, 0), 0);
        Mat centComponents = Mat.zeros(new Size(0, 0), 0);
        Imgproc.connectedComponentsWithStats(image, labeled, rectComponents, centComponents);

        // Collect regions info
        int[] rectangleInfo = new int[5];
        double[] centroidInfo = new double[2];
        regions = new Region[rectComponents.rows() - 1];

        for(int i = 1; i < rectComponents.rows(); i++) {

            // Extract bounding box
            rectComponents.row(i).get(0, 0, rectangleInfo);
            Rect rectangle = new Rect(rectangleInfo[0], rectangleInfo[1], rectangleInfo[2], rectangleInfo[3]);

            // Extract centroids
            centComponents.row(i).get(0, 0, centroidInfo);
            Point centroid = new Point(centroidInfo[0], centroidInfo[1]);

            regions[i - 1] = new Region(rectangle, centroid);
        }

        // Free memory
        rectComponents.release();
        centComponents.release();
    }

    /**
    * Extract region mask from labeled Mat
    *
    * @param region
    * @return Mat
    */
    public Mat getRegionMask(Region region) {
        int i = Arrays.asList(regions).indexOf(region);
        Mat mask = new Mat(labeled.size(), labeled.type());
        Scalar color = new Scalar(i + 1, i + 1, i + 1);
        Core.inRange(labeled, color, color, mask);
        return mask;
    }

    public Region[] getRegions() {
        return regions;
    }

    public Region getRegion(int index) {
        return regions[index];
    }

    /**
     * Call this method to release private Mat member
     */
    public void release() {
        labeled.release();
    }

    /**
    * Extract original image of the region using the region mask
    * @param image Original image
    * 
    */
    public Mat getRegionImageWithMask(Mat image, Region region) {
        Mat mask = getMask(region);
        Mat result = Mat.zeros(image.size(), image.type());
        result.setTo(new Scalar(255,255,255));
        image.copyTo(result, mask);
        Mat boxImage = new Mat(result, region.getBounding());
        mask.release();
        result.release();
        return boxImage;
    }

    /**
    * Extract original image of the region using the region mask
    * @param image Original image
    * 
    */
    public Mat getRegionImage(Mat image, Region region) {
        return new Mat(image, region.getBounding());;
    }

    public class Region {
        private Rect bounding;
        private Point centroid;

        public Region(Rect bounding, Point centroid) {
            this.bounding = bounding;
            this.centroid = centroid;
        }

        public Rect getBounding() {
            return bounding;
        }

        public Point getCentroid() {
            return centroid;
        }
    }
}
```